# SSL certificate verify failed error when trying to install gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Im on OSX 10.10.5 and using RVM and ruby version 2.3.1. When i run `gem install <gem_name>` i get the following error

> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect
>   returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
>   (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I tried with different versions of ruby but still get the same error. When i run the following command

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

I get:

```
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

I have done `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` again but still the error persists. Also trying to do `gem update --system` gives the same error.

The output of `ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` is `"OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016"`

Any way to fix this  ?

Thank You

Comment: Finally this is fixed for me. For anyone else facing the same issue, what worked for me is https://github.com/tenex/rails-assets/issues/239#issuecomment-87108900 .

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, the only way it work for me is to download the most updated rubygem from official website, then running the following command:

1. Download gem from [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download#formats)
2. Unpack rubygem zip file into any directory
3. `cd` into the unpacked rubygem folder
4. Install with: `ruby setup.rb` (you may need admin/root privilege)
5. Enter `sudo gem update --system` (to test you have most updated rubygem)

...After last step, it responded with `Latest version currently installed. Aborting` yay! Hope this helps :)